# About the comma operator in C++

Tags: c++

I have been learning C++ primer using VS 2013 community.
And when I test the following two programs. I am very confused because I think the output should be the same kind of things. Why are the results different? 
The first one is as follows.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec(10,0);
    vector<int>::size_type cnt =ivec.size();
    for (vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix != ivec.size(); ++ix)
    {
        --cnt;
        ivec[ix] = cnt;
        cout << ivec[ix] <<" "<<cnt<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the second program is as follows.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec(10,0);
    vector<int>::size_type cnt =ivec.size();
    for (vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix != ivec.size(); ++ix, --cnt)
    {
        ivec[ix] = cnt;
        cout << ivec[ix] <<" "<<cnt<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For `for (a; b; c;) { d; }`, *when* are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` executed?

Comment: The third expression in the `for` loop is not executed until after the `for` loop body has executed, unlike your first example so `--cnt` is not executed until after the body is executed

Answer (score 7):

A `for` loop like

```
for (a; b; c)
{
    d;
}
```

is equivalent to the following

```
a;
while (b)
{
    d;
    c;
}
```

So what happens in the `c` part is done *after* the body of the loop is done.

In your second case the `--cnt` expression happens *after* you use it, while in the first case the `--cnt` happens *before*.